# Why do emails I send go to their junk folder?

Tags: email, smtp

I have a problem to send email using php. Here is my code.

```
<?php
// error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_STRICT);

require_once "Mail.php";

$host = "ssl://mail12.heteml.jp";
$username = "username@mail.com";
$password = "mypassword";
$port = "465";
$to = "myname@hotmail.com";
$email_from = "from@mail";
$email_subject = "Subject Line Here:" ;
$email_body = "whatever you like" ;
$email_address = "email-address";

$headers = array ('From' => $email_from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $email_address);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $email_body);


if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
echo "<p>Message successfully sent!</p>";}
 ?>
```

This is my code. It works . But all mails are sent in their junk folder. I can't solve this problem. Please help me if you know. Thank you.

Comment: This email looks like junk to email clients. You should consider using a service like SendGrid or AWS SES to send emails.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. I have solved this problem with phpmailer library. I mistook smtp's port. Thank you. Dubinkin.